# How to get Javascript Select box's selected text

Tags: javascript, select

This things works perfectly

```
<select name="selectbox" onchange="alert(this.value)">
```

But I want to select the text. I tried in this way

```
<select name="selectbox" onchange="alert(this.text)">
```

It shows undefined.
I found how to use DOM to get text. But I want to do this in this way, I means like using just this.value.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML
```

should provide you with the "displayed" text of the selected item. `this.value`, like you said, merely provides the value of the `value` attribute.

Comment: I don't like it. While I'm sure it does work on current browsers, it's an odd mixture of DOM element-based code and old-style form manipulation code. `options` returns a list of `Option` objects, which I'm not sure are specified anywhere to be the same thing as `<option>` elements. Better to use the time-honoured `text` property of the selected `Option`, which is guaranteed to work.

Comment: Tim, `Option` objects are the same as `HTMLOptionElement` objects. If you object to using `options`, you could alternatively use `children` or `childNodes` instead (can't remember exactly which one; I think that they both work)

Comment: I think you misunderstand slightly: I'm fully in favour of using `options`, but `Option` objects predate `HTMLOptionElement` objects and there's no specification I've seen that mandates that `Option` and `HTMLOptionElement` must be the same thing, even though they may well be in most browsers that support both. My point is that it would be safer not to mix the two styles. So, I'd prefer `this.options[this.selectedIndex].text` or a node-based thing based on `selectedIndex`, which is complicated by need to filter out whitespace text nodes in IE.

Comment: That's a very good point. Just out of curiosity, if you have non-text nodes inside the option nodes, does `text` return the `innerHTML`, or just all the text nodes combined?

Comment: Geez people, stop up-voting incompetence! Oded has the correct answer. How hard is it to research the concept of the DOM? >__>

Answer (score 70):

In order to get the value of the selected item you can do the following:

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].text
```

Here the different `options` of the select are accessed, and the `SelectedIndex` is used to choose the selected one, then its `text` is being accessed.

Read more about the select DOM [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp).

Comment: `this.options[this.selectedIndex].value` is exactly the same as `this.value`, sorry.

Comment: When I use this.options[this.SelectedIndex].text error console says -
Error: this.options[this.SelectedIndex] is undefined

Comment: SHAKTI: That's because it's `selectedIndex` rather than `SelectedIndex`.

Comment: Or, just for fun, `this.selectedOptions[0].text` (with obvious extensions if you have a multiselect).

Answer (score 37):

Please try this code:

```
$("#YourSelect>option:selected").html()
```

Comment: So thanks! this returns the value of selected item in combobox

Comment: .text() actually returns the selected text

Answer (score 34):

Just use

`$('#SelectBoxId option:selected').text();`   For Getting text as listed

`$('#SelectBoxId').val();`  For Getting selected Index value

Comment: While this works perfectly for jQuery, the OP only listed javascript as an original tag.  Still, +1 since so many people use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I know no-one is asking for a jQuery solution here, but might be worth mentioning that with jQuery you can just ask for:`$('#selectorid').val()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value, you can use this code for a select element with the id="selectBox"

```
let myValue = document.querySelector("#selectBox").value;
```

If you want to get the text, you can use this code

```
var sel = document.getElementById("selectBox");
var text= sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
```

Answer (score 0):

The question was not for the value but for the text.
Imagine you have something like :

```
<select name="select">
<option value="1">0.5</option
<option value="2">0.7</option
</select>
```

And you need to catch the text.
So for me I have tried with html (php), and

```
 this.options[this.selectedIndex].text
```

(from  Delan Azabani) doesn't work but

```
 this.options[selectedIndex].text
```

work, like this  on HTML

<select ...  onChange="upTVA(this.options[selectedIndex].text);">

It is still surprising that for a select `this.text` does not work while `this.value` works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).