# To get a combobox value as innerhtml

Tags: javascript

I have a combobox and the values entered to the combobox is from the database. When I select a value I need to get it as innerHTML. How can I do that?

```
This is my html ad php code
<select name="prosp" class="textboxes" id="prosp" >
                <option onclick="prospsho(0)">--Select--</option>
                <?php $obj->prospsel();?>
                </select>


class qrys
{
    function prospsel()
    {
        $qry="select ID,NAMES from prospects ";
        $r=$this->exeqry($qry);
        while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($r))
        {
            echo "<option value=".$res['ID']." onclick='prospsho(".$res['ID'].")'>".$res['NAMES']."</option>";
        }
    }
}
```

The output in the combo box are names eg,Stephan,Danial,ect.When I select one name I should get the selected name as HTML or innerHTML using JavaScript.

Comment: This fiddle should help http://jsfiddle.net/rYAGY/1/

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: what do you mean by _as inner html_? like `<option value="a">abc</option>`? should that be the output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Javascript Select box's selected text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170648/how-to-get-javascript-select-boxs-selected-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `value` attribute. For instance:

```
<select id="combobox" onchange="log_selection(this)">
    <option selected value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<script>
    var combobox = document.getElementById('combobox');
    console.log('Combobox value is: ' + combobox.value);

    var log_selection = function(obj){
        console.log('New value is: '+obj.value)
    }
</script>
```